# RODBC Accessing Information Schema

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm trying to execute the following SQL command using the `RODBC` package in R.

(I'm trying to find all of the tables that have a column name like 'ID')

```
USE[databasename]
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%'
```

When I attempt to pass this text through the function below, I get no return:

```
library(RODBC)

  odbc <- function(x){
    query <- as.character(x)
    db <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername;trusted_connection=true')
    datadb <- sqlQuery(db, query, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    close(db)
    datadb
  }

odbc("USE[databasename]
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%'")
```

No rows are returned. If I were to execute this same text in SSMS, it returns rows. What am I misunderstanding AND/OR doing incorrectly here?

Comment: You need administrative privileges to run that meta data command. Likely your connection to SSMS is server-level admin.

Comment: @Parfait which server roles do I need to execute this meta data command?

Comment: Actually your issue may be sending two SQL commands: `USE` and `SELECT`. Try specifying the connected database in connection string and avoid using `USE`.